# How to prevent DOS/Console application that was called using Process class in .NET, from automaticly closing the command prompt after finish?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In my Winform application, I need to call a DOS or Console application and I do that with the following code:

```
    Process proc = new Process();
    proc.StartInfo.FileName = lLocation.Text+"\\pywin32.exe";
    proc.StartInfo.Arguments = lLocation.Text+"\\data.pos";
    proc.Start();
```

Problem is that after the application outputs the result on the screen, the Command Prompt closes immediately, so I can not read the result of that application.

One solution would probably be to create .bat file with "pause" command in the end and use that in the Process class, but I am wondering, if there is another way?

Comment: *MS-DOS* - seriously?!?!?! Don't you just mean a *Windows command line application* ?? MS-DOS has been history - for a **loooooong time** now...

Comment: Yeah,even though the app older versions ran in MS-DOS, now it is probably window console application.Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just read the output of the process:

```
Process proc = new Process();

proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
proc.StartInfo.FileName = lLocation.Text+"\\pywin32.exe";
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = lLocation.Text+"\\data.pos";
proc.Start();

string output = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
proc.WaitForExit();
```

Then do whatever you wish with the output.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. This worked but only after I added this code         `proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput=true;
        proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;`.Otherwise I would get exception.

Comment: Whilst that will capture the text, it won't capture any colouring which might be used to indicate things (e.g. error in red.)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to control the lifetime of the console of another process. Your batch file with a pause looks an easy trick to solve the problem. Unless you want to go the Brandon way.